# What is the best way to "roll up" aggregate data in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a large table containing hourly statistical data broken down across a number of dimensions.  It's now large enough that I need to start aggregating the data to make queries faster.  The table looks something like:

```
customer INT
campaign INT
start_time TIMESTAMP
end_time TIMESTAMP
time_period ENUM(hour, day, week)
clicks INT
```

I was thinking that I could, for example, insert a row into the table where campaign is null, and the clicks value would be the sum of all clicks for that customer and time period.  Similarly, I could set the time period to "day" and this would be the sum of all of the hours in that day.

I'm sure this is a fairly common thing to do, so I'm wondering what the best way to achieve this in MySql?  I'm assuming an INSERT INTO combined with a SELECT statement (like with a materialized view) - however since new data is constantly being added to this table, how do I avoid re-calculating aggregate data that I've previously calculated?

Comment: just use a where clause. like only aggregate values for a specific time period

Answer (score 1):

I done something similar and here is the problems I have deal with:

You can use `round(start_time/86400)*86400` in "group by" part to get summary of all entries from same day. (For week is almost the same)

The SQL will look like:

```
insert into the_table 
( select 
   customer, 
   NULL, 
   round(start_time/86400)*86400, 
   round(start_time/86400)*86400 + 86400, 
   'day', 
   sum(clicks) 
  from the_table 
  where time_period = 'hour' and start_time between <A> and <B> 
  group by customer, round(start_time/86400)*86400 ) as tbl;

delete from the_table 
where  time_period = 'hour' and start_time between <A> and <B>;
```

1. If you going to insert summary from same table to itself - you will use temp  (Which mean you copy part of data from the table aside, than it dropped - for each transaction). So you must be very careful with the indexes and size of data returned by inner select.
2. When you constantly inserting and deleting rows - you will get fragmentation issues sooner or later. It will slow you down dramatically. The solutions is to use partitioning & to drop old partitions from time to time. Or you can run "optimize table" statement, but it will stop you work for relatively long time (may be minutes).
3. To avoid mess with duplicate data - you may want to clone the table for each time aggregation period (hour_table, day_table, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the table smaller, you'll be deleting the detailed rows after you make the summary row, right?  Transactions are your friend.  Start one, compute the rollup, insert the rollup, delete the detailed rows, end the transaction.

If you happen to add more rows for an older time period (who does that??), you can run the rollup again - it will combine your previous rollup entry with your extra data into a new, more powerful, rollup entry.